# generate the seo friendly url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, seo

I am using simple php.
I want to access this url (http://localhost/url/test.php?id=10) like this

http://localhost/url/test.php/id/10

but i faced problem in this

my htaccess file look like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$
RewriteRule ^localhost/url/test/id/10$ http://localhost/url/test.php?     id=10&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `RewriteRule ^url/test/([0-9]+)$ /test.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: Its not working.
why test after url ?

Comment: so what is your expected URL?

Comment: want to access like this
http://localhost/url/test.php/id/10

instead of this http://localhost/url/test.php?id=10

Answer (score 0):

Mate

Try This

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^url/test\.php/id/([^/]*)$ /url/test.php?id=$1 [L]
```